# PHP Not Waiting For Completion Before Page Load

Tags: php, php-5.6

This is my php file - my issue is that the page displays the header before the stored procedure is ever executed.  What I am after is to have the stored procedure execute, then the select statement execute, then the results display on screen.  Do I need to use something similar to `Thread.Sleep()` in order to ensure the stored proc has time to fully execute before the code continues on?

If you need to see my calling procedure syntax let me know and I can add that in as well.  But why is the syntax displaying the table headers, before the stored procedure executes and the select statement executes?  I thought php would do things sequentially?

```
//PDO Connection
$hostname = 'Ragweed';
$dbname = 'Test';
$username = 'testuser';
$password = 'ghost';
$dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$password");

$ramalad = implode(',',$_REQUEST['ramalad']);
$df = $_REQUEST['df'];
$dt = $_REQUEST['dt'];

//Run SQL Server Parameter Stored Procedure
$sql = 'CALL storedproc(?,?)';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $df, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $dt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

//Select the selected fields from the newly created table
$sql = "SELECT ".$ramalad." FROM tablefromstoredproc";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

//Generate Header for Table
$counter = 0;
$width = count($_REQUEST['ramalad'])*110;

    echo '<div style="width:'.$width.'px;border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top: 30px;">';
    echo '<div style="width:'.$width.'px;background-color:#ccc;height:30px;">' ;
    if(in_array('EmpName',$_REQUEST['ramalad'])){ echo '<div style="width:105px; float:left; margin-right:5px;text-align: center;">Employee</div>'; }
    if(in_array('EmpID',$_REQUEST['ramalad'])){ echo '<div style="width:105px;float:left;margin-right:5px;text-align: center;">EmployeeID</div>'; }
    if(in_array('EmpHireDate',$_REQUEST['ramalad'])){ echo '<div style="width:105px;float:left;margin-right:5px;text-align: center;">Hire Date</div>'; }
    echo "</div>";

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if($counter%2 == 0 ){ echo '<div style="width:'.$width.'px;height:50px;">'; }
    else { echo '<div style="width:'.$width.'px;background-color:#ccc;height:50px;">'; }
    if(isset($row["EmpName"])){ echo '<div style="width:105px; float:left; margin-right:5px;text-align: center;">'.$row["EmpName"].'</div>'; }
    if(isset($row["EmpID"])){ echo '<div style="width:105px;float:left;margin-right:5px;text-align: center;">'.$row["EmpID"].'</div>'; }
    if(isset($row["EmpHireDate"])){ echo '<div style="width:105px;float:left;margin-right:5px;text-align: center;">'.$row["EmpHireDate"].'</div>'; }

    echo "</div>";
    $counter++;
}
unset($dbh); unset($stmt);
```

**EDIT**
From the comments and my googling php syntax is synchronous so that it should execute line 1, then line 2, then line 3 etc.  With that being the case why is my stored procedure and select statement not executed?

Comment: Fetching data from the database in PHP is synchronous.

Comment: @ChipDean - meaning it all takes place at the same time?  So I would need to add in a blocker of sorts to ensure A finishes before B starts?

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh Nope, it means that everthing is done step by step. javscript for example is async. But can you explain why you are execute a query then ouput html and after that fetching the rows? To fix it currently do `ob_start();` at the beginning and at the end of all work `ob_end_flush();`. But you should learn about how php works, first.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - I am allowing a user to select what fields they want to see in the query.  So step 1 is to execute the stored procedure, then step 2 is to query the table that is created from the stored procedure.  Step 3 based off the user selections build the header, and finally step 4 based off the user selection return the rows.  Is there a better way to achieve such?

Comment: Just simple: You can also fetch all rows into an array before create html and ouptut it. just seperate stuff. Like first preparing data & then showing data. You mix it up.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - the rows are passed from an array into the external php file.  It's coming in as `ramalad`

Comment: I was talking about the `PDO` stuff `$stmt->fetch()`. Not about the `$_REQUEST` data

Comment: You say I should fetch all rows from the database into an array?

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh maybe this example helps: http://code.runnable.com/VT4ZeoLslYQEzmzo/php-pdo-stored-procedure-for-mysql

Comment: move the `$row=stmt->fetch()` to right after `stmt->execute();`, you don't need to fetch it at `while` loop.

Comment: @b3wii - this is for mssql not mysql.

Comment: Offtopic: `$sql = "SELECT ".$ramalad." FROM tablefromstoredproc"` is vulnerable to SQL-injection. You need to use either named `:my_var` or unnamed `?` placeholders.

Comment: @hcheung - moving the `$row=stmt->fetch()` still does not prevent the page from loading before the stored procedure fully executes.

Comment: I really don't understand why you could fetch something yet not ready. Then just put some sort of condition check while no data wait (or loop), else display it.

Comment: @hcheung - I did not think I was fetching something not ready.  My thought was the stored procedure would execute, then the select statement **then** the generate table statement.  By that point there would be data to populate.